# Wordcount on SE

Tags: support

I'm interested to know how many words I've written on stackexchange (split by subsite). I can do a lot of copy and paste, but I'm interested to know if there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to get the text of each of your contributions. Then split it on the application side.

I assume you know programming since Stack Overflow is a programmer community; if you are from another Stack Exchange site you may be out of luck as far as I know.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: And, no, I don't think you can. SQL doesn't natively support word counts.

Comment: You can remove everything between <code> tags and then split on a space @Telthien. It'll give you a good idea and is probably no different to most commercial implmentations.

Comment: @ben Hmm, I assumed the DE allowed simpler queries only, but I suppose it does...